# Regex 2 Numbers OR Special Characters

Tags: regex

So i'm trying to create a Regex which does the following:

Min 12 Characters, Requires Uppercase, Requires Lowercase, Requires 2 Numeric values OR 2 Special Characters.

At the moment i have the following:

```
~^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]|\D*\d).{12,}~u
```

Which does 1 numeric OR 1 special character, not 2. I've tried adding {2} to the OR condition, however, this requires a combination of two which is incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very nice example of [regex contrast principle](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()]|\D*\d)` lookahead with `(?:(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2})|(?=(?:\D*\d){2}))`. The regex will look like

```
'~^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?:(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2})|(?=(?:\D*\d){2})).{12,}$~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0edCvC/2).

The lookahead matches a location that is immediately followed with

- `(?:[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()]){2}` - two repetitions of any 0+ chars other than `!@#$%^&*()` chars followed with a char from the `!@#$%^&*()` list
- `|` - or
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2}` - two repetitions of any 0+ non-digit chars followed with a digit

Comment: That's perfect mate. I don't quite understand "(?:(?=(?:" but it works as expected.

Comment: @JordanLowe You are using lookaheads in your regex, so I assumed you know what they mean. `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) that is good for quantifying sequences of pattenrs (see where `{2}` are placed, right after them).